# Angular 5 + Typescript - Return array of newly created typed objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service where i am retrieving "moments" from my backend. I have 2 functions. A get() method which returns 1 object and a search() method which returns an array of objects.

**moment.service.ts**

In the get method, i map the res from the backend to create a new instance of my Moment class. Which works fine.

```
   get(moment_id) {

        let endpoint = this.path + moment_id;

        return this.apiService.get(endpoint)
                              .map((res) => new Moment(res.data));
    }
```

I want to do the same except in the search method. It should map the array so all objects inside it are a new instance of the moment class.

```
search(filters) {

    let endpoint = this.path + 'search';

    let params = new HttpParams({ fromObject: filters });

    return this.apiService.get(endpoint, params)
                          .map((res) => new Array<Moment>(res));
}
```

However, this does not work the array returned does not show that the objects are of type Moment.

[image]

**moment.component.ts**

```
   moments: Moment[] = [];

    this.momentService.search(filters).subscribe((res) => {
                this.moments = res;
                console.log(this.moments);
            });
```

**moment.model.ts**

```
import { Comment } from './comment.model';
import { User } from './user.model';

export class Moment {

    _id?: string = null;
    body?: string = null;
    author?: User = null;
    likes?: any[] = [];
    dislikes?: any[] = [];
    comments?: Comment[] = [];
    created_at?: string = null;
    updated_at?: string = null;


    constructor(data?: Moment) {
        if (data) {
            this.deserialize(data);
        }
    }

    private deserialize(data: Moment) {

        const keys = Object.keys(this);
        for (const key of keys) {
            if (key === 'author') {
                this[key] = new User(data['author']);
            } else if (key === 'comments') {
                this[key] = data['comments'].map(c => new Comment(c));
            } else {
                this[key] = data[key];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instantiating moments as follows:

```
search(filters) {

    let endpoint = this.path + 'search';

    let params = new HttpParams({ fromObject: filters });

    return this.apiService.get(endpoint, params)
                          .map((res) => new Array<Moment>(new Moment(res)));
}
```

Comment: Damn , i didint see that for so long. However, i am getting a follow up error that im not getting with the simple get function. The error is "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" located in my .model.ts on "                this[key] = data['comments'].map(c => new Comment(c));" any ideas?

Comment: I just noticed the res is of type array containing objects. i think i need to send individual objects within the res[] into new Moment.

Comment: So i ended up with this - ```return this.apiService.get(endpoint, params).map((res) => res.map((x) => new Moment(x)));``` because also  new Array was creating an array around an array. A little strange that im doing 2 maps tho.

Comment: Ah, that actually makes sense. First `map` is probably rsxjs' `map`, whereas the second one is `Array.prototype.map`. Glad you got it working.